# P&T Checkboxes not displaying properly

Tags: pixelandtonic, pt-checkboxes

I'm having trouble getting my P&T Checkboxes field to display properly.

My field is {job_type} and it's options are: 
full_time : Full-time
part_time : Part-time

This is the code I'm trying to use, but it doesn't ouptut anything:

```
{exp:channel:entries}   
  {job_type backspace="2"}{option}, {/job_type}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If I change it to just {job_type}, it outputs the selected value as part of a list; but if I try to use the proper :ul tag, {job_type:ul}, it doesn't output anything.

I'm using EE 2.5.5, and P&T Checkboxes version 1.0.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the tag pair to work with EE 2.5.5 and PT Field Pack 1.0.3 you need to modify the ft.pt_checkboxes.php file and add has_array_data = true;

```
class Pt_checkboxes_ft extends PT_Multi_Fieldtype {

var $info = array(
    'name'     => 'P&amp;T Checkboxes',
    'version'  => PT_FIELD_PACK_VER
);

var $class = 'pt_checkboxes';

var $has_array_data = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

artmem,

I just tested this. I have a checkbox (pt_checkbox) with three options.   I threw this into a template to test the output:

```
    {exp:channel:entries limit="1"}
<h1>{title}</h1>
    {pt_check}
    {option_name}: {option}<br />
    {/pt_check}
<hr />
{/exp:channel:entries}

<hr />

{exp:channel:entries limit="1"}
<h1>{title}</h1>
{pt_check:ul sort="asc"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

and both sets of tags gave me the correct output, as:

[image: Screenshot of Output]

Does a very simple test like that work for you?  I'm also testing on 2.5.5 and 1.0.3.

Comment: I tried it. Your second example (the UL tag) did work, but the first, with the tag pair gave no results.

Comment: That is a bit odd.  Are you able to upgrade to Field Pack 2 for further testing? If that doesn't get this working, I'd be happy to login and do some direct troubleshooting. :)

Comment: I tried to upgrade to Field Pack 2, but I can't get it to install. I uploaded the files to the proper locations, but when I go to my Fieldtypes page in the CP to install them, they don't show up. I've moved my third_party outside of the system folder. Could that be an issue? I haven't had any problems with other add-ons.

Comment: What do you have set in your config for the third_party path?  If you'd like me to look at this directly, Super Admin and FTP details to support@pixelandtonic.com would be ideal.

Comment: Just emailed login info & details.

Answer (score 0):

Field Pack 2.0.2 requires EE 2.6 at least. Having same issue with EE 2.5.5 and fieldpack 1.03